# Rename duplicate files in a zip file Java

Tags: java, string, file, rename, archive

I have several files including duplicates which I have to compress into an archive.Do you know some tool able to rename duplicate files before creating the archive ex(cat.txt, cat(1).txt, cat(2).txt ...)?

Comment: Are you sure this is a Java question?

Comment: Why not? He added the Java tag, thus he wants to make it in Java, thus we give him a Java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created the following code that easily removes duplicates:

```
static void renameDuplicates(String fileName, String[] newName) {
    int i=1;
    File file = new File(fileName + "(1).txt");
    while (file.exists() && !file.isDirectory()) {
        file.renameTo(new File(newName[i-1] + ".txt"));
        i++;
        file = new File(fileName + "(" + i + ").txt");
    }
}
```

Use is simply as well:

```
String[] newName = {"Meow", "MeowAgain", "OneMoreMeow", "Meowwww"};
renameDuplocates("cat", newName);
```

The result is:

```
cat.txt     ->    cat.txt
cat(1).txt  ->    Meow.txt
cat(2).txt   ->   MeowAgain.txt
cat(3).txt   ->   OneMoreMeow.txt
```

Keep on mind that the number of duplicates should be smaller or equal than alternative names in the array of string given. You can prevent it with **while** cycle modification to:

```
while (file.exists() && !file.isDirectory() && i<=newName.length)
```

In this case the remaining files will keep unnamed.

Comment: Thanks, but what  I was thinking was that there is some library doing this thing for me.

Comment: I don't know any. Anyway using a small piece of code up to 10 lines should be fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add static field in some class with some initial value.

```
static int number = 1;
```

Then in your java code you may rename duplicates in this way using java 8 streams and Files class :

```
Set<String> files = new HashSet<String>();

    youCollectionOfFiles.stream().forEach((file)->{
        if (files.add(file.getFileName().toString()) == false) {
            try {
                //rename the file
                Files.move(file, 
                        file.resolveSibling(file.getFileName().toString() + (number++)));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    });;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try an approach like this one:

```
File folder = new File("your/path");
HashMap<String,Integer> fileMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
    if(fileMap.containsKey(listOfFiles[i])){
             String newName = listOfFiles[i]+"_"
                +fileMap.get(listOfFiles[i]);
             fileMap.put(listOfFiles[i],fileMap.get(listOfFiles[i])+1);
             listOfFiles[i].renameTo(newName);
             fileMap.put(newName,1); // can be ommitted
    }else{
            fileMap.put(listOfFiles[i],1);
    }
}
```