# Rename duplicate files using java and mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, duplicates, file-rename

I am trying to make a system which involves "file management" so the only thing that bothers me is how to rename file duplicates like for example:

- "Cat.docx" becomes Cat(1).docx
- "Cat(1).docx" also becomes Cat(2).docx and so on...

I also understand the other thread answers related to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35286965/rename-duplicate-files-in-a-zip-file-java)
But I am using **Mysql** Database with Java and I honestly cannot think of a way to adapt it in my case.

Anyone with an idea about it, please share. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are storing fileName in database, then you can follow these steps

1. If you are getting a file name file.txt then make a call to db with

   select count(*) from table where fileNmae="file.txt"
2. If this count is greater than 0 then insert file into table with name file(1).txt (for renaming follow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35286965/rename-duplicate-files-in-a-zip-file-java))
3. If count is 0 then directly insert the original name into table.

Comment: I was so frustrated that I overlooked the count function of mysql. Thanks man!